# Creating bins and extracting values for that bin

Tags: python, pandas, intervals, bin

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like

```
   Temperature_lim  Factor
0           32       0.95
1           34       1.00
2           36       1.06
3           38       1.10
4           40       1.15
```

I need to extract factor value for any given temperature , if my current temperature is 31, my factor is 0.95. If my current temp is 33, factor is 1, if my current_temp is 38.5 factor is 1.15. So by giving my current temperature, i would like to know the factor for that temperature.

I can do this using multiple if else statements, but is there any effective way I can do it by creating bins/intervals in pandas or python.

Thank you

Comment: Provide expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) with add `-np.inf` to values of column `Temperature_lim` and missing values by last value of `Factor` value:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Temp':[31,33,38.5, 40, 41]})

b = [-np.inf] + df['Temperature_lim'].tolist()
lab = df['Factor']

df1['new'] = pd.cut(df1['Temp'], bins=b, labels=lab, right=False).fillna(lab.iat[-1])
print (df1)
   Temp   new
0  31.0  0.95
1  33.0  1.00
2  38.5  1.15
3  40.0  1.15
4  41.0  1.15
```

Comment: thanks, but  with this I will not be able to get the factor for temp value of 38.5 right ?

Comment: the new data frame `df1` created will have discrete set of values, if i want the factor value for a  temp of `38.5` or `38.3` such create data frame has to be created to extract the factor for that temp.

Comment: @cvg - yop, answer was changed for `41` value.

Comment: Hi @jezrael  I need a help on pandas

Comment: @pyd - what exactly?

Comment: I have emailed you, could you please check, attached the relevent pickle file